# Trying to understand "derivative or Jacobian of smooth map"

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

From some lecture notes I am trying to puzzle through ....

"... the derivative or Jacobian of a smooth map $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $x$ is a linear map $Df: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.  In terms of partial derivatives,  $Df_x(X) = (\sum_j\partial_{x_j}f_1 \cdot X_j,
\sum_j \partial_{x_j}f_2\cdot X_j, ...)$ ... "

I'm so confused I'm not even sure where to begin.  Well, first, shouldn't the derivative be a map $Df:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$?  Third, I am familiar with 3D integral calculus, and the only Jacobian I heard discussed there doesn't look like this at all, except, of course, that they both involve partial derivatibes.  Also, I don't even know what $f_1 \cdot X_j$ means.

Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila  I now understand that "jacobian" isn't an "official" topic tag.  But wouldn't it be a good one to have?

Comment: I'm a big believer in have a discussion before adding new tags (and in general opposed to adding new tags, unless strong evidence in favor are presented). If you think that it would make a good addition (and it might be), you should head to the [meta] site, and start a discussion thread about this. Preferably bring evidence to support that this would be a good tag (e.g. the fact that many questions ask about this topic, and that it will be hard to locate this information via other reasonable means). Then add the tag.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to think about the derivative is:
\begin{equation*}
\tag{$\spadesuit$}f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + f'(x) \Delta x.
\end{equation*}
The approximation is good when $\Delta x$ is small.  This equation expresses the fact that $f$ is "locally linear" at $x$.

How can we make sense of ($\spadesuit$) when $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$?
\begin{equation*}
f(\underbrace{x}_{n \times 1} + \underbrace{\Delta x}_{n \times 1}) \approx \underbrace{f(x)}_{m \times 1} + \underbrace{f'(x)}_{?} \underbrace{\Delta x}_{n \times 1}.
\end{equation*}

It appears that $f'(x)$ should be something that, when multiplied by an $n \times 1$ column vector, returns an $m \times 1$ column vector.  In other words, $f'(x)$ should be an $m \times n$ matrix.

If we prefer to think in terms of linear transformations rather than matrices, we can write
\begin{equation*}
f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + Df(x) \Delta x.
\end{equation*}
Here $Df(x)$ is a linear transformation that takes $\Delta x$ as input, and returns $f'(x) \Delta x$ as output.  This equation is what it means to be "locally linear" in the multivariable case.

Taking this as our starting point, it's not too hard to show that
\begin{equation*}
f'(x) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial f_1(x)}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1(x)}{\partial x_n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_m(x)}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m(x)}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
(The functions $f_i$ are the component functions of $f$.)

If 
\begin{equation*}
X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_n \end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}
f'(x) X = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f_1(x)}{\partial x_j} X_j \\
\vdots \\
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial f_m(x)}{\partial x_j} X_j
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation*}
as you can see just by doing the matrix-vector multiplication.
This is the equation given in your question.

Comment: OK, so as I understand it, my problems have involved notation and nomenclature.  I was expecting the writer to say that the derivative was actually the matrix you have in your answer.  To my mind, that matrix represents a mapping from R^m to R^(mxn).  (I wrote that wrongly in my question.  Oh well.)  That is, to my mind, the matrix is the *result of* a mapping.  But he is saying the matrix *is* a map (or a representation of ...).  And the "inputs" to the map are the *X*'s, not to be confused with the *x*'s.  The *X*'s being sort "delta x's".  How's that?

Comment: A key point is that an $m \times n$ matrix represents a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$.  Not a mapping from $\mathbb R^m$ to $\mathbb R^{m \times n}$.  The matrix is not the *result* of this mapping.  The matrix represents a linear transformation that takes a vector as input and returns a *vector* as output.  You are right when you say that $X$ is an input to this linear transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If $f: \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ is a differentiable mapping then at every $x \in \Bbb R^m$ its derivative $Df_x$ is a linear mapping from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$, therefore $Df_x \in \operatorname{Lin}(\Bbb R^m, \Bbb R^n)$. The elements of the matrix representing $Df_x$ are the partial derivatives of the partial functions of $f$. When you have $m=n$ you have the case of the Jacobian matrix.

Consider the implications of your question: if $Df$ were a mapping from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R^n$ then for $m=n=1$ we'd have that the derivative of real functions of one variable is a point in $\Bbb R^2$.

Applying a vector $X \in \Bbb R^m$ to $Df_x$ you obtain a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ whose entries are the product of rows in $Df_x$ by the vector $X$. In symbols,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \partial_1 f_1 & \cdots & \partial_m f_1 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \partial_1 f_n & \cdots & \partial_m f_n \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ \vdots \\ X_m \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_{j=1}^m \partial_j f_1 X_j \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{j=1}^m \partial_j f_n X_j \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I wrote incorrectly in my question.  I should have said a derivative looks to me like a map from R^m to R^(mxn), kind of like a gradient of z(x,y) is a map from R^2 to R^(2x1).  Or that's the way I was looking at it.  Thanks for your answer.