# How can I determine the double derivative of a function $f:R^n \to R$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

A function $f:R^n \to R$ belong to $C^2$. So $Df$ will be a matrix of order "1 by n". So now the range set of function $Df$ will be all row matrix of order "1 by n" while domain set will remain same(set of all column matrix of order "n by 1"). Then how can I handle this function? How would I determine $D^2f$? Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Have you ever done it for some $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$? In any case, see the [hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix)

Comment: for functions $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ you will probably need the concept of tensors

Comment: I have just started reading MVC. Can you please tell me about the function $Df$? what is it's domain and range? How would I differentiate it again?@AndresMejia

Comment: $Df$ is a "linear approximation" of a function $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$. Try to compute if for $f(x,y)=x+y$. This is the "trivial case" where the function is already linear. Try then to compute $f(1,1)+Df(1,1)(\mathbf{x}-(1,1))$. Next you can try a function $f(x)=x^2+y^2$ and do the same computation. Evaluate the difference between $f$ and the expression I give for $\mathbf{x}=(1,1.1)$ and $\mathbf x = (1.1,1)$. I'm not really a teacher, so I don't know the best way to internalize this kind of thing. Try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) or Hubbard's bk.

Comment: There is the following property of the standard derivative: $f(a+\Delta x) \approx f(a)+f^{\prime}(a) \cdot (\Delta x)$. In this sense, $f^{\prime}(a)$ is the best linear approximation near $a$ (since a one dimensional matrix is multiplication. The situation is similar in higher dimensions, but linear transformations now take the form of matrices. In your case $n \times 1$ matrices applied to $n$-vectors

Comment: The trouble with the second derivative is that in each co-ordinate direction, you now have to see how an $n \times 1$ "row" is behaving, so for each $x_i$ you get a column, and hence at the end an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: I am trying to get your point. Once I am done , I will tell how much I have understood.@AndresMejia

Comment: Don't look too closely! They're just kind of rambles. Try [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914556/trying-to-understand-derivative-or-jacobian-of-smooth-map) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14952/what-is-jacobian-matrix) for much better discussions.

Comment: If $f(x,y) = x+y$ then $$Df :  \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ \\ X_2 \end{bmatrix} \to (1 , 1)$$ Now how can I differentiate $Df$?@AndresMejia

Comment: Well $Df$ IS constant so I think there is a pretty fair guess for the derivative.

Comment: But I am feeling inconvenient to handle because it's domain point is a column matrix where it's image is a row matrix.@AndresMejia

Comment: How can I determine $D^2f$ from the definition. Can I use $lim \frac {f(a+h) - f(a) - B.h}{|h|}$ this definition to determine it's derivative? Here $f(a+h)$ , $f(a)$  are row matrices of order "1 by 2" where $h$ is a column matrix of order "2 by 1" Then how can I get a Matrix $B$?@AndresMejia

Comment: I'm not sure how much more commenting is SE-acceptable, but the definition can be used to show that you have *found* the derivative but is in practice not helpful in determining what the derivative is. You should instead calculate the jacobian and then prove that this is indeed the derivative.

Comment: How can I determine $D^2f$ from the definition. Can I use $lim \frac {f(a+h) - f(a) - B.h}{|h|}$ this definition to determine it's derivative? Here $f(a+h)$ , $f(a)$  are row matrices of order "1 by 2" where $h$ is a column matrix of order "2 by 1" Then how can I get a Matrix $B$ because $Bh$ will always be a column matrix?@AndresMejia

Comment: okay. I am using definition because this a petty problem. But there must be a problem .  Can you please point out where did I go wrong?@AndresMejia